# locust Memory Issue

Tags: python, locust

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\o-ddong\work\test\ - locust\venv\lib\site-packages\locust\user\task.py", line 347, in run
    self.execute_next_task()
  File "d:\o-ddong\work\test\ - locust\venv\lib\site-packages\locust\user\task.py", line 372, in execute_next_task
    self.execute_task(self._task_queue.pop(0))
  File "d:\o-ddong\work\test\ - locust\venv\lib\site-packages\locust\user\task.py", line 493, in execute_task
    task(self.user)
  File "D:\o-ddong\Work\test\ - locust\send.py", line 37, in diagnose_report
    req = self.client.post("/diagnose/", data=data.encode('utf-8'), headers=headers, name="diagnose")
  File "d:\o-ddong\work\test\ - locust\venv\lib\site-packages\locust\contrib\fasthttp.py", line 280, in post
    return self.request("POST", url, data=data, **kwargs)
  File "d:\o-ddong\work\test\ - locust\venv\lib\site-packages\locust\contrib\fasthttp.py", line 215, in request
    response = self._send_request_safe_mode(method, built_url, payload=data, headers=headers, **kwargs)
  File "d:\o-ddong\work\test\ - locust\venv\lib\site-packages\locust\contrib\fasthttp.py", line 128, in _send_request_safe_mode
    return self.client.urlopen(url, method=method, **kwargs)
  File "d:\o-ddong\work\test\ - locust\venv\lib\site-packages\geventhttpclient\useragent.py", line 459, in urlopen
    last_error = self._handle_error(e, url=req.url)
  File "d:\o-ddong\work\test\ - locust\venv\lib\site-packages\geventhttpclient\useragent.py", line 424, in _handle_error
    raise reraise(type(e), e, sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "d:\o-ddong\work\test\ - locust\venv\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 719, in reraise
    raise value
  File "d:\o-ddong\work\test\ - locust\venv\lib\site-packages\geventhttpclient\useragent.py", line 454, in urlopen
    resp = self._urlopen(req)
  File "d:\o-ddong\work\test\ - locust\venv\lib\site-packages\locust\contrib\fasthttp.py", line 546, in _urlopen
    client = self.clientpool.get_client(request.url_split)
  File "d:\o-ddong\work\test\ - locust\venv\lib\site-packages\geventhttpclient\client.py", line 306, in get_client
    client = HTTPClient.from_url(url, **self.client_args)
  File "d:\o-ddong\work\test\ - locust\venv\lib\site-packages\geventhttpclient\client.py", line 68, in from_url
    return cls(url.host, port=url.port, ssl=enable_ssl, **kw)
  File "d:\o-ddong\work\test\ - locust\venv\lib\site-packages\geventhttpclient\client.py", line 107, in __init__
    self._connection_pool = SSLConnectionPool(
  File "d:\o-ddong\work\test\ - locust\venv\lib\site-packages\geventhttpclient\connectionpool.py", line 241, in __init__
    self.init_ssl_context(ssl_context_factory)
  File "d:\o-ddong\work\test\ - locust\venv\lib\site-packages\geventhttpclient\connectionpool.py", line 256, in init_ssl_context
    self.ssl_context = ssl_context_factory()
  File "d:\o-ddong\work\test\ - locust\venv\lib\site-packages\locust\contrib\fasthttp.py", line 65, in insecure_ssl_context_factory
    context = gevent.ssl.create_default_context()
  File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\ssl.py", line 750, in create_default_context
    context.load_default_certs(purpose)
  File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\ssl.py", line 574, in load_default_certs
    self._load_windows_store_certs(storename, purpose)
  File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\ssl.py", line 562, in _load_windows_store_certs
    certs.extend(cert)
MemoryError
```

#### Describe the bug

When the number of users increases while running locust, a memory issue occurs. so it stops

#### Expected behavior

I expected locust to run continuously and not increase the number of users to the limit.

#### Actual behavior

Like the code above, a MomoryError is raised

#### Steps to reproduce

Please forgive me for not uploading the code 100%

```
from locust import FastHttpUser, task, between, constant


class User(FastHttpUser):
    host = "hostURL"

    @task(1)
    def send(self):
        headers = {}
        req = self.client.get("URL", headers=headers)
    
    wait_time = constant(1)
```

#### Environment

PC performance : i5-9600K, 32 RAM
python version : 3.8
locust version : 2.14.2
Infra : m5.large server 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting unexpected `MemoryError` and as you mentioned you have 32GB of RAM then there should be plenty of RAM available, it might be because you are using a 32-bit python installation.

The easy solution, if you have a 64-bit operating system, is to switch to a 64-bit installation of python.

The issue is that 32-bit python only has access to ~4GB of RAM. This can shrink even further if your operating system is 32-bit, because of the operating system overhead.

It is not possible to directly upgrade a 32bit Python installation to a 64bit one.

What you can do is freeze the requirements using:

`pip freeze > requirements.txt`

This will freeze all the requirements and their versions in requirements.txt file.
After installing the new python version, just run: `pip install -r packages.txt`, this will install all the packages and their required versions in the new environment.